# CCParticleSystemQuad incorrect colors from Particle Designer?

Tags: ios, colors, cocos2d-iphone, particles, ccparticlesystem

I am using the latest version of Cocos2D and Particle Designer and I have noticed that the colors are not the same in Cocos2D from the way they look in the simulator in Particle Designer. In particular I am trying to achieve a more orange color for my particles but whatever I try the particles are always a yellowish color.

In particular whenever I increase the starting Red value or the particle animation, I see no changes in the Red color of the animation in Cocos2D. I must also note I did not have this issue in Cocos2D 1.x so something must have broke. Could it have done with this pull request? https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/pull/205

Is there some certain source and destination blending function I am supposed to use with Cocos2D 2.x to get the results I see in Particle Designer's simulator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your particle system probably is in additive blending mode (source: GL_SRC_ALPHA, destination: GL_ONE). IIRC, Particle Designer's default background is black (rgb 0, 0, 0), so visible color of particles in its preview is not changed. Working as intended; set an image of your in-app background as preview background and experiment with blending mode settings.

Comment: I think it was in additive blending mode. Should it be in the normal blending mode with my game background as the background in the simulator and then I make it look however I want? Right?

Comment: Play with blending modes and pick whatever you like more.